How to use minio S3 bucket in Uploadcare?
How can one use a minio s3 bucket with uploadcare.com? Uploadcare allows you to upload files directly to your AWS S3 storage. Since minio is s3 compatible storage i'm wondering how to use that instead?
Unfortunately the uploadcare settings ui only asks for a (AWS) bucket name. Does it imply that only AWS s3 is supported?

As of September 2024, Uploadcare has native integration with AWS S3 only. Integration with other S3-compatible storage providers might be added in the future.
